# Bootrap 4.1.1 Banner image and navbar not full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a new page in Bootstrap 4.1.1. I can't get the banner image and the navbar to be full width. The page is [live here](http://www.pscompetitiveedge.com/) Can you figure out what I did wrong in the code? I posted the relevant parts of the code for the problem. I've used Bootstrap before, just not this newest version. Thanks in advance

```css
body{color:#000;font-size:20px}
.masthead img{width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(images/Banner.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
background-size:cover;}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #FF8C46;
}


/* change the brand and text color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
text-decoration: none; color: #000;
}

a.navbar-brand:link,
a.navbar-brand:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000; 
  border-radius: 50px; padding: .5rem;
}
a.navbar-brand:hover,
a.navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* change the link color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
   text-decoration: none; color: #000;
}

/* change the color of active or hovered links */

.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom  {
  text-decoration: none;  color: #000;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;   
}

/* for dropdown only - change the color of dropdown */

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #FF8C46;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-item {
    text-decoration: none; color: #000;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:focus {
    text-decoration: none; color: #000;
    background-color:#FF8C46;
}
.navbar-toggler {
   border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #000;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon:hover {
  background: #036;
}

span.navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<header class="masthead">
<img src="http://www.pscompetitiveedge.com/images/Banner.jpg" alt="Peter Scott's Competitive Edge logo"/>
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
<button class="navbar-toggler drpbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>     
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="programs.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-fire fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> Programs</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="references.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-users fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> References</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="rates.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> Rates</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="faq.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-question fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> FAQ</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> Contact</a>
</li>
</ul> 
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/peter-scott/44/3/6b3" target="_blank"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="tel:1-520-977-5695"><span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-phone-volume fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span> Call Peter</a>
</li>
</ul>       
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="container"> 
<-- the page content goes here -->
```

Comment: if you right click in browser and select 'Inspect' you can have a look at whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem:

```
.container-fluid{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

I do not know if you only want to use bootstrap, so if yes don't use this code.

I hope I helped you,

Greetings.

Comment: No problem, and if you have some problem with the design after adding this code it's because there is other divs with this name in the page you're styling.

Comment: So I suggest you to add a custom id in this div and use the name of the id you choose instead of this class in your stylesheet to ensure not to destroy any other div  with this name.

Comment: I was just about to ask about my vertical carousel. I can't seem to get the prev and next buttons separated with space. Should I make a new thread for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170726/discussion-between-alexandre-beaupre-and-mlegg).

Comment: In this case i will recommend declaring a second class and assigning those values to that class. So you dont mess the .container-fluid for future use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the container class `.container-fluid` assigns 15px of padding to the sides

**For Bootstrap 4**, You need to use jumbotrons

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/)

**For Bootstrap 3**, you need to use `.container-full`

**Extra** solution will be overriding Bootstrap class with :

```
.container-fluid{
  padding: 0;
}
```

In this case i will recommend declaring a second class and assigning those values to that class. So you dont mess the `.container-fluid` for future use.

Answer (score 0):

So I messed with your code on chrome developer tools and noticed that `<div class="container-fluid">` had padding on the left and right side. Once, I checked those off, the banner went the whole page. I would try overriding it and setting a padding of 0px.